# Android photo app to change photo background

Tags: gratis, android, photography

I'm looking for a free Android photo editing app that is able to easily cut out the subject of the photo and put it on a white background.

There are many apps in Google Play called *Background Photo Changer* or similar but many of these have a large number of 1-star reviews indicating they're fake.  I want to install a legitimate, tested app.